# jQuery - object dissapears as soon as I put it in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Couldn't find about this problem, I guess it's not really a problem, just I don't know how to it.
On the event of click on a certain div, I want to open it a new tab. I managed to do it in the following code, but what happens is the original div disappears from the original page and is showed only in the new tab, I'm not quite sure why this is happening, but I though about cloning the object - but wasn't successful.

This is the relevant code:
open new tab on click:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(){
    window.toSend = $(this);   
    window.newTab = window.open("test.html", "_blank");
```

add the object to the new tab:

```
var data = parent.window.opener.toSend;
    $(".clickedButton").html(data);
```

Any solutions? or first, why is this even happening? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `window.toSend = $(this).clone();` ?

Comment: never felt dumber (it works). thanks! can you explain why this happend? why putting the object in another place removed from the original appearance?

Comment: I have updated an answer with the reason.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery website:
(https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> As shown in the discussion for .append(), **normally when an element is inserted somewhere in the DOM, it is moved from its old location...**
> ...
>
> To prevent this and instead create a copy of the element, you could write the following:

`$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" );`

So in your case:

`$(this).clone();`

Comment: > when an element is inserted somewhere in the DOM, it is moved from its old location... ...

This is the exact reason.  I have formatted in bold to emphasize.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the div:

`window.toSend = $(this).clone();`

clone creates a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

Using `$(this)` you selected the element, so when you place it somewhere else it is moved from here. It is like picking and moving the element in DOM.

Whereas `clone` make a copy of the element so the original element is not afected. It is ike creating a copy and placing that copy somewhere else in DOM